# VB code is no debug error but not effecting the report, how it would be solved?

Tags: vba

```
Sub ProfitLoss_Refresh()
Dim PLRow As Long
Dim LastTransRow As Long
Dim LastResultsRow As Long
Dim AcctRow As Long**

 With Sheet1
    .Range("B7:I99999").ClearContents 'Clear Existing Report
    LastTransRow = Sheet2.Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last transaction row 

   Sheet2.Range("P3:Q3").ClearContents 'clear prev criteria
    Sheet2.Range("w3:aa99999").ClearContents 'clear prev results 

   If .Range("e3").Value <> Empty Then Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=" & _
       .Range("E3").Value Else: Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=01/01/2000" 'from date
```

I checked the date format, but didn't find anything: if you like to check the file and guide me, i can give you through wikicopy.com? – Mr. Ali 11 hours ago
even there are some code or Data issue, there must be debug error, but running full, but after that data disappears from AdvancedFilterResults, if it is clear from there, then nothing will effects the other area of the report.

Comment: There is no end with ..Can you give the file? And you are not applying advanced filter here so why the result will be shown in your sheet?

Comment: wikisend.com/download/962510/P&L-1.xlsm here is the file

Comment: after giving the file no one reply, i don't know !

Comment: Your file is too large..I will reach to you after seeing your file..

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Your code has error in this line: Sheet2.Range("B2:f" & LastTransRow)........
And the error code say that your extract range has  a missing or invalid field name.

Comment: But with me, it is solved, still not working

Comment: @Ali just replace your code with my...Just this portion.

Comment: Sheet2.Range("B2:f" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=Sheet2.Range("p2:q3"), copyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("w2:aa2"), Unique:=True

You're saying to change here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok check this now;

```
Sub ProfitLoss_Refresh()
Dim PLRow As Long
Dim LastTransRow As Long
Dim LastResultsRow As Long
Dim AcctRow As Long
With Sheet1

.Range("B7:I99999").ClearContents 'Clear Existing Report
LastTransRow = Sheet2.Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last transaction row
Sheet2.Range("P3:Q3").ClearContents 'clear prev criteria
Sheet2.Range("W2:AA99999").ClearContents 'clear prev results
If .Range("e3").Value <> Empty Then Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=" & .Range("E3").Value Else: Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=01/01/2000" 'from date
If .Range("g3").Value <> Empty Then Sheet2.Range("q3").Value = "<=" & .Range("g3").Value Else: Sheet2.Range("q3").Value = "<=31/12/2030" 'to date
Sheet2.Range("B2:F" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheet2.Range("P2:U3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("W2:AA2"), Unique:=True
LastResultsRow = Sheet2.Range("w99999").End(xlUp).Row
If LastResultsRow < 3 Then GoTo NoResults
PLRow = 7 'starting point for Profit & Loss Statement

'add in Income Accounts
For AcctRow = 3 To 999
If Sheet2.Range("J" & AcctRow).Value = "Income" And Sheet2.Range("k" & AcctRow).Value <> 0 Then 'only on income type account
    .Range("D" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("I" & AcctRow).Value 'account name
    .Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("K" & AcctRow).Value 'account amount
    PLRow = PLRow + 1
   End If
Next AcctRow
.Range("C" & PLRow).Value = "total Income"
.Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("TotIncome").Value 'add in total income amount
PLRow = PLRow + 2

'add in COGS
.Range("C" & PLRow).Value = "COGS"
PLRow = PLRow + 1
For AcctRow = 3 To 110
If Sheet2.Range("J" & AcctRow).Value = "COGS" And Sheet2.Range("k" & AcctRow).Value <> 0 Then 'only on income type account
.Range("D" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("I" & AcctRow).Value 'account name
.Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("K" & AcctRow).Value 'account amount
PLRow = PLRow + 1
End If
Next AcctRow
.Range("C" & PLRow).Value = "total COGS"
.Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("Totcogs").Value 'add in total COGS amount
PLRow = PLRow + 1
.Range("b" & PLRow).Value = "total Gross Profit"
.Range("I" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("grossprofit").Value
PLRow = PLRow + 2

'add in expenses
For AcctRow = 3 To 110
If Sheet2.Range("J" & AcctRow).Value = "income" And Sheet2.Range("k" & AcctRow).Value <> 0 Then 'only on income type account
    .Range("D" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("I" & AcctRow).Value 'account name
    .Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("K" & AcctRow).Value 'account amount
    PLRow = PLRow + 1
   End If
Next AcctRow
.Range("C" & PLRow).Value = "total Expenses"
.Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("totexpenses").Value 'add in total Expenses amount
PLRow = PLRow + 1
.Range("b" & PLRow).Value = "total Net Profit"
.Range("I" & PLRow).Value = Sheet2.Range("netprofitloss").Value
NoResults:
```

End With
End Sub

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221916/discussion-on-answer-by-md-ismail-hosen-vb-code-is-no-debug-error-but-not-effect).